# How to connect textfield in cell as an outlet to a table view cell class swift

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have a dynamic table view. I wanted to connect the textfield in a cell to my view controller but I got this error "Outlets cannot be connected to repeating content". I searched for help and found that you should connect your outlets to your cell class. But I am unable to connect my textfield as an outlet. I can only as an action. I have correctly gave the class to the cell. Thanks

Comment: Are you sure the textField is a subview of the cell?

Comment: yes it is, it is in the content view.

Comment: And you made sure the cell-class is the class you are trying to add the Outlet?

Comment: Try adding the IBOutlet code manually, then drag from the circle to the left of it to the TextField in your cell in storyboard.

Comment: Glad it helped.  Have had the same problem myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure that you are using a custom class of `UITableViewCell`, and update the class in the Identity Inspector for your cell.

If Control-dragging from the storyboard `UITextField` to the Code does not work, create the code first and drag from the circle to the left of the code to the `UITextField` in the storyboard.

```
@IBOutlet var yourTextField: UITextField!
```

Answer (score 0):

Try after restarting Xcode, Add this line to you Cell-Class and then try to control-drag outlet on to this outlet:

```
@IBOutlet var myCustomLabel: UITextField!
```